# Visual Studio: System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net

```
Option Strict On
Public Class MortgageCalculatorFRM
```

`Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles calculatePaymentBTN.Click
    Dim amount As Integer
    Dim interestRate As Double

    If amountTBX.Text.Equals("") Or interestTBX.Text.Equals("") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter an amount and an interest rate", "Invalid Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

    amount = CInt(amountTBX.Text)
    interestRate = CDbl(interestTBX.Text)<code>`

I am trying to check if the amountTBX or interestTBX is empty, if it is, then messagebox will appear. The MessageBox appears however, once I clicked on OK, I'm getting this error: **System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'** I need help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the validation fails, you don't want to proceed any further. Add a [return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/return-statement) statement after the MessageBox.

```
If amountTBX.Text.Equals("") Or interestTBX.Text.Equals("") Then
    MessageBox.Show("Enter an amount and an interest rate", "Invalid Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Return
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will check correctly and show the message to user, but after showing the message the code will continue to run because you haven’t said otherwise. That’s why the conversion is still attempted. You need to exit the sub after:

```
If amountTBX.Text.Equals("") Or interestTBX.Text.Equals("") Then
    MessageBox.Show("Enter an amount and an interest rate", "Invalid Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Exit Sub
End If
```

You could also use `Else` but usually it’s clearer to exit in checks and not increase nesting with `Else`.